# I think [poster-color] tag should be added

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags

I have a question about my Arts & Crafts Stack Exchange post: [Can I mix poster colors on a plastic pallet](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/10875/can-i-mix-poster-colors-on-a-plastic-pallet)

**I think that the tag `poster-color` should be added to Arts & Crafts.**

As poster colors are both a medium of art/painting and also a very popular means of painting, especially among students, I think this tag should be added.

Comment: Note that "a medium of art" and "a very popular means of painting" are basically the same thing ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right: [here](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/poster-color) it is.

Comment: Thank You for adding the tag!